# Disabling all controls until the thread finishes executing

Tags: c#

Once i launch a win forms application, i create a background worker to do some initialization. While this initialization happens, i want all the buttons in the form to stay disabled.

I was thinking whats the best way to do this. One straightforward approach i could think of is setting a flag in the thread's completed event. Is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this I typically put the controls into a `Panel`, disable the panel when the background process is started, and then enable it again when the work is done. This way you don't need to keep track of the `Enabled` state for each individual control. Disbling the panel and starting the background worker can be done in the form's `Load` event handler (or `OnLoad` override, depending on your coding style).

Answer (score 1):

We can use a delegate disablealldelegate to disable all controls in thread initialization and when the thread exits we can use another delegate enablealldelegate to enable all the controls(or required controls)

Use of splashscreens or loadingscreens or a login form is also feasible

Answer (score 0):

There is the old "show a screenshot of the application" trick; it gives the illusion of near-instant startup time, and of course the user can't interact with the controls until you replace the image with the initialized form.

You can keep the form hidden until initialization completes, showing a splash screen instead.

You can show a modal dialog that closes itself once initialization completes.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the buttons in the Form Designer by default.

I would then add code to the end of my initialization method to enable them once the rest of the initialization is complete.

Answer (score 0):

should do : Check http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/270381-best-practice-waiting-worker-thread-complete